# Python Regex - How to Get Positions and Values of Matches

Tags: python, regex

How can I get the start and end positions of all matches using the `re` module? For example given the pattern `r'[a-z]'` and the string `'a1b2c3d4'` I'd want to get the positions where it finds each letter. Ideally, I'd like to get the text of the match back too.

Comment: See if this helps [Match Objects](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/match-objects.html)

Answer (score 193, accepted):

```
import re
p = re.compile("[a-z]")
for m in p.finditer('a1b2c3d4'):
    print(m.start(), m.group())
```

Comment: This doesnt provide index of other groups in a match
regex=r'([a-z])(0-9)'
m.start will be for group(), not group(1)

Comment: @StevenWernerCS `start()` may accept a group number, so if you want an index of nth group, use `start(n)`

Comment: @hi-angel yep, see my answer below from last year that does just that

Answer (score 69):

Taken from

[*Regular Expression HOWTO*](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/regex.html)

> span() returns both start and end indexes in a single tuple. Since the
>   match method only checks if the RE matches at the start of a string,
>   start() will always be zero. However, the search method of RegexObject
>   instances scans through the string, so the match may not start at zero
>   in that case.

```
>>> p = re.compile('[a-z]+')
>>> print p.match('::: message')
None
>>> m = p.search('::: message') ; print m
<re.MatchObject instance at 80c9650>
>>> m.group()
'message'
>>> m.span()
(4, 11)
```

Combine that with:

In Python 2.2, the finditer() method is also available, returning a sequence of MatchObject instances as an iterator.

```
>>> p = re.compile( ... )
>>> iterator = p.finditer('12 drummers drumming, 11 ... 10 ...')
>>> iterator
<callable-iterator object at 0x401833ac>
>>> for match in iterator:
...     print match.span()
...
(0, 2)
(22, 24)
(29, 31)
```

you should be able to do something on the order of

```
for match in re.finditer(r'[a-z]', 'a1b2c3d4'):
   print match.span()
```

Comment: You can use it like `re.search(r'abbit', "has abbit of carrot").span(0)` -- `(4, 9)`

Comment: The 'end index' returned by the `span()` is like the 'stop' in Python's slice notation in that it goes up to but doesn't include that index; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/8508004).

Answer (score 32):

For Python 3.x

```
from re import finditer
for match in finditer("pattern", "string"):
    print(match.span(), match.group())
```

You shall get `\n` separated tuples (comprising first and last indices of the match, respectively) and the match itself, for each hit in the string.

Answer (score 17):

note that the span & group are indexed for multi capture groups in a regex

```
regex_with_3_groups=r"([a-z])([0-9]+)([A-Z])"
for match in re.finditer(regex_with_3_groups, string):
    for idx in range(0, 4):
        print(match.span(idx), match.group(idx))
```

Comment: Thanks, this has proved super useful and seems to be quite buried. Also, in case anyone needs this: when using named capture groups, one can find the index of a group using <match>.re.groupindex, and from there find the corresponding span using the approach you outlined

Comment: where does the `4` come from?

Comment: @RadioControlled number_of_known_groups_in_the_regex + 1, as range is [start,end) exclusive of end

Comment: @StevenWernerCS so it does not generalize to cases where number of groups is not known...

Comment: You can generalize it to an unknown number of groups by changing `range(0, 4)` to `range(0, len( match.groups() ))`.