# how to extract the value fom script using python regex in webscraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn how to use regex to extract values using python.

here is the script,so how to get the salesprice,seller_name and skuId

```
<script>
define('app/pc', ['//laz-g-cdn.alicdn.com/lzdfe/pdp-platform/0.1.8/pc.js'], function(app) {
try {
    app.run( {
        "data": {
            "root": {
                "fields": {"skuInfos": {
                        "0": {
                            "categoryId":"8711", "dataLayer": {
                                "pdt_category":["Mother & Baby", "Feeding", "Milk Formula", "Follow On (6 - 12 mnths)"], "pagetype":"pdp", "pdt_discount":"-8%", "pdt_photo":"//laz-img-sg.alicdn.com/original/6bdf9b4b759b97f57b438a605f0e37e7.jpg", "v_voya":1, "brand_name":"Dumex", "brand_id":"30360", "pdt_sku":153105871, "core": {
                                    "country": "SG", "layoutType": "desktop", "language": "en", "currencyCode": "SGD"
                                }
                                , "seller_name":"Dumex", "pdt_simplesku":191142180, "pdt_name":"Dumex Mamil Gold Stage 2 Follow On Baby Milk Formula (850g)", "page": {
                                    "regCategoryId": "180101030000", "xParams": "_p_typ=pdp&_p_ispdp=1&_p_item=DU741TBAATAO7DSGAMZ-61110782&_p_prod=153105871&_p_sku=191142180&_p_slr=100047849"
                                }
                                , "supplier_id":100047849, "pdt_price":"47.9"
                            }
                            , "image":"//laz-img-sg.alicdn.com/original/6bdf9b4b759b97f57b438a605f0e37e7.jpg", "inWishlist":false, "itemId":"153105871", "operation": {
                                "operationWeight": 6, "text": "Add to Cart", "type": "default"
                            }
                            ,  "price": {
                                "discount":"-8%", "originalPrice": {
                                    "text": "SGD47.90", "value": 47.9
                                }
                                , "salePrice": {
                                    "text": "SGD44.29", "value": 44.29
                                }
                            } ,
                            ], "sellerId":"100047849", "skuId":"191142180", "stock":18, "stockList":[ {
                                "stoock": 18, "type": "default"
                            }
                            ]
                        }
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you need regex? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7570485

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Regex - How to Get Positions and Values of Matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250271/python-regex-how-to-get-positions-and-values-of-matches)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be based on a combination of HTML parsing, regex and json loading:

- locate the desired `script` element with `BeautifulSoup` (you've shown a single `script` element, but I assume it is actually inside a bigger HTML)
- extract the desired Javascript object using regular expressions
- use `json.loads()` to load it into a Python dict/list
- get the desired things from this Python object

Smth along these lines:

```
import json
import re
from pprint import pprint

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
<script>
define('app/pc', ['//laz-g-cdn.alicdn.com/lzdfe/pdp-platform/0.1.8/pc.js'], function(app) {
try {
    app.run( {
        "data": {
            "root": {
                "fields": {"skuInfos": {
                        "0": {
                            "categoryId":"8711", "dataLayer": {
                                "pdt_category":["Mother & Baby", "Feeding", "Milk Formula", "Follow On (6 - 12 mnths)"], "pagetype":"pdp", "pdt_discount":"-8%", "pdt_photo":"//laz-img-sg.alicdn.com/original/6bdf9b4b759b97f57b438a605f0e37e7.jpg", "v_voya":1, "brand_name":"Dumex", "brand_id":"30360", "pdt_sku":153105871, "core": {
                                    "country": "SG", "layoutType": "desktop", "language": "en", "currencyCode": "SGD"
                                }
                                , "seller_name":"Dumex", "pdt_simplesku":191142180, "pdt_name":"Dumex Mamil Gold Stage 2 Follow On Baby Milk Formula (850g)", "page": {
                                    "regCategoryId": "180101030000", "xParams": "_p_typ=pdp&_p_ispdp=1&_p_item=DU741TBAATAO7DSGAMZ-61110782&_p_prod=153105871&_p_sku=191142180&_p_slr=100047849"
                                }
                                , "supplier_id":100047849, "pdt_price":"47.9"
                            }
                            , "image":"//laz-img-sg.alicdn.com/original/6bdf9b4b759b97f57b438a605f0e37e7.jpg", "inWishlist":false, "itemId":"153105871", "operation": {
                                "operationWeight": 6, "text": "Add to Cart", "type": "default"
                            }
                            ,  "price": {
                                "discount":"-8%", "originalPrice": {
                                    "text": "SGD47.90", "value": 47.9
                                }
                                , "salePrice": {
                                    "text": "SGD44.29", "value": 44.29
                                }
                            } ,
                            "sellerId":"100047849", "skuId":"191142180", "stock":18, "stockList":[ {
                                "stoock": 18, "type": "default"
                            }
                            ]
                        }
</script>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

pattern = re.compile(r'"skuInfos": {\s+"0": ({.*})$', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

script = soup.find("script", text=pattern)

json_string = pattern.search(script.get_text()).group(1)
data = json.loads(json_string)


print(data['price']['salePrice']['value'])
print(data['skuId'])
print(data['dataLayer']['pdt_category'])
```

Prints:

```
44.29
191142180
['Mother & Baby', 'Feeding', 'Milk Formula', 'Follow On (6 - 12 mnths)']
```

Note that for this to work I had to fix a syntax error in the JS itself as I think this is not a full script you actually have. In any case, I can imagine you would need to adjust the pattern to better match the desired JS object(s) for your specific use case.

Comment: you are right the script is in bigger html,so this script is in 124 th in html page so how to i select the 124th position script and pass the patten?