# how to identify 2 differnet strings exists in a prargraph

Tags: python-3.x, text, spacy

I have 2 different lists which contains names and location. Need to identify position of both name and location in text.

Input

> Name:['Mughal'] Location: ['Panipat','Agra']
>
> text=['The battle of Panipat laid the foundation of the Mughal dynasty
>   in Agra.']

Output:

> Start position:15;end position:21;Word:Panipat;type:Location; Start
>   position:50;end position:55;Word:Mughal;type:Name

code:

```
for t in (text):
for n in name_:
    while index_ < len(t):
        index_ = t.find(n,index_)
        if index_ == -1:
            break
        else:
            kwmatch.append((index_, index_+len(n),"Name"))
            index_  += len(rect) 
    index_ = 0
a = (text,{'entities':kwmatch})
doctuple.append(a)
kwmatch = []
a = None
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you have already done so far ?  The community can then help you out with the code . Thanks

Comment: @muralidhar A have you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250271/python-regex-how-to-get-positions-and-values-of-matches

Comment: @Gagan wrote for list not able to understand,converting that to multiple lists

Comment: You can use a dictionary to make your life much easier, check if my answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, it will be much easier to save your `Name` and `Location` data, if you were to use dictionaries (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). e.g.

```
dct = {
    'Name'  : ['Mughal'],
    'Location':  ['Panipat','Agra']
}
```

After that, you can iterate over each text in your list of text, find the starting and ending index of the words using [string.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.find), and your word and type can be taken from the word you are searching, and the key.

```
text=['The battle of Panipat laid the foundation of the Mughal dynasty in Agra.']

for t in text:
    for key, value in dct.items():
        for v in value:
            #Starting index using find
            start_pos = t.find(v)+1
            #Ending index after adding the length of word
            end_pos = start_pos+len(v)-1
            #Word and type are the word we are looking for, and the key of the dictionary
            print('Start position: {}; end position: {}; Word: {}; type: {}'.format(start_pos, end_pos, v, key))
```

The output then comes up as.

```
Start position: 50; end position: 55; Word: Mughal; type: Name
Start position: 15; end position: 21; Word: Panipat; type: Location
Start position: 68; end position: 71; Word: Agra; type: Location
```