# Regex: Smallest possible substring match

Tags: python, regex

I have url strings such as:

```
"https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/slide_3/"
```

Now, I need to capture the `slide_3` part, more specifically the start position of the digit `3`  on constraint that it should be a single digit( neither preceded nor succeeded by any digit) not preceded by an "=". So, `pageid=2` shouldn't match while `slide_3` should.

I tried this with python regex:

```
p = re.compile('/.*(?<!=)(?<!\d)\d(?!\d).*/')
s = "https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/slide_3/"

for m in p.finditer(s):
    print(m.start(), m.group())
```

and the result is

```
6 //facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/slide_3/
```

I understand why I get this, the first and the last "/" satisfy the regexp but so does the substring "/slide_3/".

How do I make sure I get the **smallest** substring that matches the regex.

Why doesn't this work:

```
'/[^/](?<!=)(?<!\d)\d(?!\d).*/'
```

Non greedy operator `.*?` does not seem to do the trick since it does not guarantee the shortest possible match.

Strings that should match:

```
"https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/slide_3/" 
"https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/sno3/"
"https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/3/"
```

and the matches should be  slide_3 , sno3, 3 respectively

Strings which shouldn't:

```
"https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/slide/"
"https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/slide_33/"
"https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/33/"
```

Comment: What is the point to use regex here?

Comment: @OlvinRoght I have multiple urls like this one, which may or may not contain the said pattern. I need to find the ones which do and further manipulate them

Comment: If I got it right the pattern is `\w_(\d)` ? After an underscore and without any number after

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx: Smallest possible match or nongreedy match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919982/regex-smallest-possible-match-or-nongreedy-match)

Comment: If match `^.*?\/slide_\d\/?$` then do your thing.

Comment: @UliSotschok IHAd gone through it, didn't work for me, would you be able to produce a regex using the non-greedy operator..?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus should probably add this in the question, the "slide" string isn't fixed here, it can be anything say "s3" or simply "3"

Comment: Yes, you should edit your question to include various examples of things which should and should not match. I think `^.*?\/[^\d]*(\d)\/?$` is what you might be looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question then you can use this to check if a string matches your expected pattern:

```
(?:^.*\/)([^\d]*\d)(?:\/?$)
```

and `\1` will contain:

```
slide_3
sno3
3
```

https://regex101.com/r/h0rNdC/4

---

This could be useful in getting the index of the match: [Python Regex - How to Get Positions and Values of Matches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/250271/2191572)

Comment: I already mentioned I need the smallest substring that matches regex, your answer matches the whole string.

Comment: @Alzio See my edit. You need to make sure to only pay attention to `\1`

Comment: @Alzio If my answer helped then please feel free to accept it as the correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could match the forward slash, then match 0+ times any char except a digit, `/`, `=` or a newline.

Capture a single digit in a capturing group and match the trailing forward slash.

To get the start and the end indices of the match, you could for example use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) which will return a [match object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

```
/[^\d/=\r\n]*(\d)/
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MmNcy3/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/mZSlKF)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"/[^\d/=\r\n]*(\d)/"
strings = [
    "https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/slide_3/",
    "https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/sno3/",
    "https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/3/",
    "https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/slide/",
    "https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/slide_33/",
    "https://facty.com/ailments/body/10-home-remedies-for-styes/pageid=2/33/"
]

for s in strings:
    matches = re.search(regex, s)
    if matches:
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end} value:{group}".format(groupNum = 1, start = matches.start(1), end = matches.end(1), group = matches.group(1)))
```

Result

```
Group 1 found at 74-75 value:3
Group 1 found at 71-72 value:3
Group 1 found at 68-69 value:3
```