# Get partial string with other string

Tags: python

I don't know how to do something like this in python:

I have a string `s = 'windows 95 is not a windows nt operating system'`, and I want to get string that contains 'nt' and a number of nearby letters, including spaces.

Expected output for 7 nearby letters:

```
'indows nt operat'
```

If it is impossible, then is it possible to get the index of a string I want to find like this:

```
>>> s = 'windows xp horray'
>>> stringtofind = 'hor'
```

Expected output:

```
11, 12, 13
```

Where I only want to get `11` because it is the start."

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Regex - How to Get Positions and Values of Matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250271/python-regex-how-to-get-positions-and-values-of-matches)

Comment: sounds like a class assignment, smells like homework

Comment: just developing a flask app with a search function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.find` with slicing.

**Ex:**

```
s = 'windows 95 is not a windows nt operating system'
to_find = 'nt'
print(s[s.find(to_find)-7:s.find(to_find)+ 7]) 
# --> indows nt oper
```

Answer (score 0):

```
position = S.index("nt")
S.[position-7:position+7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `find()` to get the index of the substring in the main string and then get the part that you want:

```
s = 'windows 95 is not a windows nt operating system'
substr = 'nt'
index = s.find(substr)
result = s[index-7: index+len(substr)+7]
print(result)
```